# What would be wrong if we store the instances of class in a treeset

Tags: java

Hi i have one doubt that,
I stored the instance of a class in a arraylist.
What would be wrong if we store the instances of class in a treeset instead of arraylist?

can any one help me in brief description?

Comment: This depends *highly* on your use case. In addition, `TreeSet` and `ArrayList` are not comparable collections, and neither is a drop-in replacement for the other. Do you know the difference between the two?

Comment: I currently store my clothes in a dresser.  What would be wrong if I stored them instead in a closet?

Comment: Thanks for all.. I understood wt u said.. but can any tell me the brief description for this in java?

Comment: Brief description for *what*?

Comment: Why don't you read the javadoc of TreeSet? That's the best way to understand what a TreeSet is. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand the differences between a `Set` and a `List`.

- A `List` is an ordered collection of elements that allows the same element to appear in the collection multiple times.
- A `Set` is an unordered collection of elements that allows an element to appear at most once in the collection.

If your application requires `Set` semantics, then replacing an `ArrayList` with a `TreeSet` would work.  Otherwise, it wouldn't.  In fact, it would probably break your application.